# Error #1503 with AIR3.4 but not AIR3.2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm working on an Android/iOS app using Adobe AIR. The app appears to work normally both inside Flash Pro and real devices except for the following test:

1. Do Publish Preview inside Flash Pro.
2. Close the preview window.

The error appears in the Output panel:

`Error: Error #1503: A script failed to exit after 30 seconds and was terminated.
    at [*code location is a for loop inside writeExternal() of a class saved to a Shared Object*]
Test Movie terminated.`

This happens with AIR3.4, but not AIR3.2. I did a lot of code checking, tracing, etc. but still can't figure out what's wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: It appears as though the FlashPlayer has started an operation, but because you have closed the  preview window the operation cannot be completed. Try not closing the window too early ;)

Comment: Yes, this error usually indicates an infinite loop. However, there's no error in AIR3.2 or Flash Player 11.4. If I close the window after 2 minutes, I get the same error.

Comment: Can you post any code that reproduces the error?

Comment: Here's the code: 

`public function writeExternal(output:IDataOutput):void 
{
 output.writeInt(_array.length);

 var i:int;

 for (i=0; i < _array.length; i++) 
 {
  output.writeInt(_array[i]._score);    
 }
}` 

I think it's a bug in AIR3.4 I tried AIR3.5 beta and the error disappeared.